# i am using ubuntu12.04,unable to install tools and packages showing error

Tags: source-packages

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ninja is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

deepak@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install cscope
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package cscope is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

[these type of error it is showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rC33h.png)

Comment: Did you do a `sudo apt-get update` first? Cheers, Al

Comment: i tried this also in that case also the same type of error was coming, but now this is resolved,  thanks

Comment: Tell us the fix! Cheers, Al

Comment: sudo apt-get clean
sudo mv /var/lib/apt/lists /tmp
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update

Answer (score 3):

This should fix it:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo mv /var/lib/apt/lists /tmp
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

Then try again.